# Wordpres core-update theme renames theme folder name

Tags: theme-development, updates, automatic-updates, git, github

I've got a theme that checks for a new version on GitHub. When it finds a new version it downloads it and install it. The problem is that it installs the theme with a different folder name than previous. Resulting errors.

I call the updater with hook `pre_set_site_transient_update_themes`

In it I check the GitHub api with: `https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/releases/latest`

I set the update `package` variable with `https://api.github.com/repos/my-name/my-repo/zipball/0.1.0` Where `0.1.0` is the latest version.

So if I install a theme manually the theme root folder is called something like: `my-theme`. Updating the theme downloads a new set of files with a different theme folder name. Something like `my-theme-3d547d1`. Next update its again being renamed, something like `my-theme-58fa412`.

How can I prevent this? Is this something on the GitHub side where I rename the target's zip file name or Something wordpress side, where it renames the zip after download and before install?

#in short#

**Wordpress renames the theme folder when fetching theme update from GitHub, how to prevent this**

Comment: WordPress wouldn't be renaming the folder anything like that. This is likely the folder/zip name given by GitHub, and you'll need to account for it in your code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, correct. It removes the current theme version folder and inserts a new theme version with a folder name bases on the name of the downloaded zip file.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct upon reading this was that a Wordpress Plugin may give you more control over this behaviour. Have you considered writing a plugin to pull and apply the updates?

A quick Google on the subject found this:

https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Any use?

Likewise, reviewing their implementation may give you clues as to how to address your issue.

Comment: Yes, almost. This plugin I saw, but it was too intensive to implement. Plus the client could disable the extra plugin it installed. Instead I found a older repo of him which had the answer to check and rename the downloaded folder: https://github.com/afragen/github-theme-updater/blob/27dfd76d14aba60714aeb44b3e19fec2820ba827/classes/class-theme-updater.php#L149-L170 This solved my problem. 
Now I can implement the thought of this process within my theme.